# Решить линейное диофантово уравнение с произвольным числом переменных

Tags: c#, c++, c, алгоритм, математика

Есть задача подбора цены: есть количество и общая сумма но нет цен по каждой позиции и есть условие что бы цены не превышали определенные коэффициенты.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить линейное диофантово уравнение с несколькими переменными?

Например:

```
a * x1 + b * x2 + ... z * xN = C
```

где:

`a,b..z и C` —  заданные целые числа,

`x1,x2...xN`  — неизвестные целые числа.

И существует условие при котором неизвестные x1,x2,xN не должны превышать определенные заданные коэффициенты `x1 <= z1`,  `x2 <= z2`, `xN <= zN`, 
где `z` заданные числа.

По данной ссылке есть решение только для двух http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_diofant_2_equation

Не могу понять как масштабировать алгоритм для нескольких неизвестных:

```
int gcd (int a, int b, int & x, int & y) {
    if (a == 0) {
        x = 0; y = 1;
        return b;
    }
    int x1, y1;
    int d = gcd (b%a, a, x1, y1);
    x = y1 - (b / a) * x1;
    y = x1;
    return d;
}

bool find_any_solution (int a, int b, int c, int & x0, int & y0, int & g) {
    g = gcd (abs(a), abs(b), x0, y0);
    if (c % g != 0)
        return false;
    x0 *= c / g;
    y0 *= c / g;
    if (a < 0)   x0 *= -1;
    if (b < 0)   y0 *= -1;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Из условия задачи не следует, что задача - диофантово уравнение, так на `С` и `X_n` не накладывается ограничение целочисленности. Покопайтесь в сторону симплекс-метода, скорее всего он вам и поможет.

Comment: @Mirdin вообще-то желательно что бы у нас не было таких значений как  например 1.33333333 (1 рубль и 3 копейки в периоде), и в качестве икс тут хотелось бы использовать именно копейки. За симплекс-метод спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: К сожалению, от рубля и трех копеек в периоде, вам никуда не сбежать :). Это эмпирический результат десятилетнего стажа работы финансистом. Я для этого поменял профессию :).

Answer (score 1):

Написать программу решающую диофантовы уравнения n переменных невозможно. На данный момент если я не ошибаюсь существуют алгоритмы вплоть до n = 4 и все они не будут похожи на алгоритм для решения уравнения с двумя переменными. Это [10 проблема Гильберта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0), которая разрешена и доказывает что это невозможно.

Comment: на самом деле - в топике не диофантово уравнение :), тс КМК напутал.

Comment: @Mirdin  а какое это уравнение?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov ИМХО это не уравнение (точнее не какое то особое уравнение), это задача на оптимизацию. В институте, решение подобных задач, более сложных - несколько, очень нелюбимых студентами, курсов занимает (Линейное алгебра, Оптимизация и тд). К сожалению, я эти задачи решал, в последний раз, лет 10 назад, так что сейчас, сходу, вам мало что подскажу.